# How to remove Na values from dataset consist of 90% of na in data frame

Tags: r

Hi I need help on how to remove NA values from my data frame.. My dataset has 90% of na value.. In almost every row and column.. When I tried using using na.omit, complete.cases, na.rm=true and many other options but when I used them all my rows getting deleted.. Need help in my project. 
Thank you

Part 2
Thank you so much. Very insight full and yes after following your instructions, the output is yes all the rows contains at least one NA value and that's the reason I'm unable to use na.Omit  or any other function.. How to Rectify it now?

Comment: Wht is your expected output?

Comment: When, as you say, 90% of your data is NA and you use `na.omit`, which deletes entire rows even if there's a single `NA`, there is a great chance that nothing will be left over!

Comment: Please don't edit a closed, answered question to ask a second question. I this question is answered, you should consider accepting the answer (by ticking the checkmark next to the answer) and asking a new question. I would also recommend that before you do so, that you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read more about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing even a snippet of your data it's tricky to help you. But from what you describe it seems that you have so many rows with `NA` that using, for example, `na.omit`, which deletes entire rows even if only a single row cells is `NA`, will effectively empty the whole dataframe. You can easily check how many rows have `NA`values:

How many rows contain NA?

```
sum(rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0)
```

Does **every** row contain `NA`?

```
nrow(df) == sum(rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0)
```

If this test evaluates to `TRUE`then indeed every row contains at least one cell with `NA`. If it evaluates to `FALSE` then there's at least one row with complete cases.

To see which rows do **not** contain `NA`:

```
df[!rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0, ]
```

To subset on the `NA`-free rows you can reuse this code:

```
df_new <- df[!rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0, ]
```

or simply use `na.omit`:

```
df_new <- na.omit(df)
```

Data:

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(
  d1 = c(rep(NA, 3), round(rnorm(7),3)),
  d2 = c(round(rnorm(6),3), NA, round(rnorm(3),3)),
  d3 = c(round(rnorm(2),3), rep(NA,2), round(rnorm(6),3)),
  d4 = c(round(rnorm(1),3), NA, round(rnorm(8),3))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very insight full and yes after following your instructions, the output is yes all the rows contains at least one NA value and that's the reason I'm unable to use na.Omit  or any other function.. How to Rectify it now?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. The question how to rectify is difficult to answer as I don't know your data and the way you've collected it.

Comment: Ok is there anyway I can upload the data here?

Comment: What you can always do is post the first 10 rows or so of your data. But the questions for you to address are really: why do I have so many `NA`? Is there a way I can avoid (that many) `NA`s? And, most important, do I really have to remove all rows with `NA`? (Maybe that's no necessary at all!)